# Text input if cell > than 1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would only like the values in Column A to return if there is a value of >1 in Column B - I am unsure on a formula to do this

[image]

Comment: by "return", do you mean visibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(A57:A66, B57:B66 > 1)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!